# (Answered) New Input System not Working at Timescale 0 even when Update Mode is set to "Process Events in Dynamic Update"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I've been learning the new input system for Unity, and everything *was* working great, until timescale is set to 0 and no input gets read at all. I've looked through other forums and found that I should have Update Mode set to "Process Events in Dynamic Update", but it turns out that was enabled by default.

Am I doing anything wrong here? Or is there something I'm missing?

here's my code: If I remove the part that sets Time.Timescale to 0 (located in a different spot), it works great, but with it in even my Print() functions do nothing

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class QuickMenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int MenuItemsAmount;
    public float cursorMoveSpeed;


    int cursorPosition;
    float progress;
    public Animator MenuHost;
    public void action(int id)
    {
        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (id == 0)
        {
            MenuHost.SetBool("Continue", true);
        }
        if (id == 1)
        {
            MenuHost.gameObject.GetComponent<killPlayerFromUI>().kill();
        }
        if (id == 2)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
    public void moveCursor(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        print("moving");
        if (context.performed)
        {
            if (context.ReadValue<float>() != 0)
            {
                if (context.ReadValue<float>() < 0)
                {
                    cursorPosition++;
                }
                else
                {
                    cursorPosition--;
                }
            }

            if (cursorPosition > MenuItemsAmount)
            {
                cursorPosition = 1;
            }
            if (cursorPosition < 1)
            {
                cursorPosition = MenuItemsAmount;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        progress = Mathf.MoveTowards(progress,cursorPosition,cursorMoveSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
        animator.SetFloat("Blend",progress);

    }
    public void Submit(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        print("submitting");
        if(context.performed)
        {
            action(cursorPosition);
        }
    }
    public void Back(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.performed)
        {
            MenuHost.SetBool("Continue", true);
        }
    }

    public void timeReturn()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}
```

Here's my Player Input Component that I'm using for this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZnec.png)

Comment: Where are all your `public` methods called from?

Comment: @derHugo Do you mean the Public Voids? They are getting called by the player Input component. I'm using the Unity Events method. They work fine when time.Timescale !=0, but once it's zero none of my inputs get registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
It turns out that if I switch from using the UnityEvents to using the C# class, (and also switch to using Time.UnscaledDeltaTime), it works just fine.

[Check "Generate C# class" box in the Input Action Asset Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myFDK.png)

Then subscribe to the InputAction.ActionMap.Action.performed Event, after making a variable which is defined to a new InputAction() asset. (Make sure to set InputAction, ActionMap, and Action to the names of the respective Input action assets, Action Maps, and Actions) Also I needed to make a new OnDestroy() function that unsubscribes to the event when the object is destroyed so I don't get any errors.

Additional note: do not assign the InputAction to a new InputAction() when first declaring it, do it in the start() function instead.
Updated Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class QuickMenuScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int MenuItemsAmount;
    public float cursorMoveSpeed;

    int cursorPosition;
    float progress;
    public Animator MenuHost;
    RollItGeneralInputs input;

    private void Awake()
    {
        input = new RollItGeneralInputs();

        input.QuickMenu.Enable();
        
        input.QuickMenu.MoveCursor.performed += moveCursor;
        input.QuickMenu.Submit.performed += Submit;
        input.QuickMenu.Back.performed += Back;
        
    }
    public void action(int id)
    {
        if (GetComponent<Animator>() == null) return;

        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (id == 0)
        {
            MenuHost.SetBool("Continue", true);
        }
        if (id == 1)
        { 
            MenuHost.gameObject.GetComponent<killPlayerFromUI>().kill();
            MenuHost.SetBool("Continue", true);
            
        }
        if (id == 2)
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }
    }
    public void moveCursor(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (!context.performed) return;

        if (context.ReadValue<float>() != 0)
        {
            if (context.ReadValue<float>() < 0)
            {
                cursorPosition++;
            }
            else
            {
                cursorPosition--;
            }
        }

        if (cursorPosition > MenuItemsAmount)
        {
            cursorPosition = 0;
        }
        if (cursorPosition < 0)
        {
            cursorPosition = MenuItemsAmount;
        }

    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        progress = Mathf.MoveTowards(progress,cursorPosition + 1,cursorMoveSpeed*Time.unscaledDeltaTime);
        animator.SetFloat("Blend",progress);

    }

    public void Submit(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Debug.Log("submitting " + cursorPosition);
        if (!context.performed) return;

        action(cursorPosition);

    }
    public void Back(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        print(MenuHost);
        if (!context.performed) return;
        if (MenuHost == null) return;


        input.QuickMenu.MoveCursor.performed -= moveCursor;
        input.QuickMenu.Submit.performed -= Submit;
        input.QuickMenu.Back.performed -= Back;

        print(MenuHost);
        MenuHost.SetBool("Continue", true);

        

    }
    private void OnDestroy()
    {

        input.QuickMenu.MoveCursor.performed -= moveCursor;
        input.QuickMenu.Submit.performed -= Submit;
        input.QuickMenu.Back.performed -= Back;
    }
    public void timeReturn()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }

}
```

Another note: to subscribe to an event, just do:

```
nameOfEvent += NameOfFunctionToCallOnEvent
```

then to unsubscribe just do

```
nameOfEvent -= PreviousFunctionYouSubscribedTo
```

in this case the nameOfEvent would be
the InputAction.ActionMap.Action.performed event we did earlier.